A planar graph has no bridges and no pair of faces share multiple edges. Then it has two faces with the same number of edges.
A planar graph $G$ has no bridges and no two faces have more than one common edge.

Prove that $G$ has two faces that have the same number of edges.

Attempt:
We can use the Euler characteristic formula and properties of graphs.
Understanding the given conditions:

The graph is planar.
There are no bridges (an edge whose removal increases the number of connected components).
No two faces share more than one edge.
Applying Euler's formula: For a connected planar graph, Euler's formula states: $V−E+F=2$
Let $f_i$ be the number of edges of face $i$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^F f_i = 2E$$


Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Please edit your question to show your attempt.
